# Monitoring/highlighting terminal stdout for keywords

Tags: terminal, monitoring, putty, tail, bash

Because our recent development work, I was put into a position where I have to monitoring a few of our application's output logs, specifically I am looking for a certain error code(s). Because my limited scripting skill right now the only thing I can do is to `tail -f` the log file and just keep looking for update. I also use PuTTY. I am hoping someone can make a few suggestions on how I can accomplish either one of the following, if possible:

1. Modify bash.rc so when certain keyword(s) displayed in terminal they will be highlighted
2. Utilize PuTTY's audio/visual bell so whenever a keyword is displayed alert will go off

Answer (score 0):

coloring your output could be done by just adding a sed regexp to your tail -f, i.e.

```
tail -f somefile.log | sed 's/keyword/highligtedkeyword/g'
```

just add some escape sequences for color..the bell part i'm not really sure about..